# how to read all the nodes and its fields and display like table?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

how to read all the nodes and its fields and display like table?

I have node/content caled TravelInvoice

Invoice Number
Invoice Date
Student Number
Months Paid (List Field) - Apr to March

some students may pay Apr only, some may pay Apr, May, Jun, some may pay full (Apr-Mar).
one student may pay Apr, Jun (in one Invoice), July, August, Sept (in another Invoice).

But when I check the pending fee for Apr.  It display the student too those already paid.

because each Invoice contain all the months (as list) and particular months only selecting for payment

how can I merge paid months from several TravelInvoices into one, so that I can verify easily from one content itself?

months are stored as List field

may be in the

first receipt  - Apr, Jun
second receipt - Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct
third receipt - Nov, Dec
so on...

I used Views Mege Fields for this..

but I get like the below...

[image]

Comment: Will you please elaborate how months are being saved w.r.t the invoice?

Comment: months are stored as List field

may be in the

first receipt - Apr, Jun second receipt - Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct third receipt - Nov, Dec so on...